# Web Extension - document.getElementById returning null before execution of async method

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, getelementbyid, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a chrome/firefox web extension. When clicked, this web extension appends a DIV, which contains several other DIVs and a iFrame in a nested structure, to the inside of the `<body>` element in a website's HTML file. It does this through the usage of a content script.

Here is the simplified code of the `onMessage` listener in the content script:

```
    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {

    var iFrame = document.createElement("iFrame");
    iFrame.id = "contentFrame";
    iFrame.style.cssText = "width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;";
    iFrame.src = browser.extension.getURL("inject.html");

    var boxDiv = document.createElement("div");
    boxDiv.style.cssText = "background: white; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 9px 8px; height: 100%; left: calc(100% - 390px); position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 390px; z-index: 1;"

    var zeroDiv = document.createElement("div");
    zeroDiv.style.cssText = "position: fixed; width: 0px; height: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2147483647;";

    var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");

    boxDiv.appendChild(iFrame);
    zeroDiv.appendChild(boxDiv);
    outerDiv.appendChild(zeroDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(outerDiv);

    var closeButton1 = document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("close-btn");
    console.log("Close Button1 Fetched: " + closeButton1);

    //closeButton.onClick = function () {
    //  console.log("Close button clicked");
    //}

    returnSummary(message.summaryLength, message.targetURL).then(summary => {

        var closeButton2 = document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementById("close-btn");
        console.log("Close Button2 Fetched, Setting Listener: " + closeButton2);

        closeButton2.onClick = function() {
            console.log("Close button clicked");
        }
    });
});
```

For context - `returnSummary` is an async function that contains a bunch of fetch requests.

The odd part is as follows:

The first log statement: `console.log("Close Button1 Fetched: " + closeButton1);` returns `null`,

but the second log statement: `console.log("Close Button2 Fetched, Setting Listener: " + closeButton2);` returns `[object HTMLButtonElement]`.

Thus, the `document.getElementbyId` seems to be working after the async request finishes. Why is this happening, and how can I retrieve the value of the HTML element with the ID `close-btn` as early as possible? (I want to set an `onClick` listener on the button).

Another odd problem is that even when I set the `onClick` method of the object `closeButton2`, clicking on the "close button" does nothing. But, that's not the primary issue of this post.

Also here is the HTML inside "inject.html", (the top is mostly just CSS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
<!-- TODO: Create Loader -->

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    .btn {
        width: 25%;
        height: 35px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid currentcolor;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        color: dodgerblue;
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .btn:hover {
        background: #2196F3;
        color: white;
    }

    #summary {
        width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        min-height: calc(100% - 75px);
        max-height: calc(100% - 55px);
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-y: auto;
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #52575C;
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 10%; min-height: 55px; max-height: 75px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center;">
        <button class="btn" id="close-btn">Close</button>
        <button class="btn" id="copy-btn">Copy</button>
    </div>
    <p id="summary"/> Loading Summary...
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Access the iframe's contentWindow only inside onload event callback for the iframe.

Comment: How do I add an event listener for the "onload" event inside an iFrame, I searched around stackoverflow and there seem to be multiple ways to do it, such as `iFrame.addEventListener` to `document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentDocument.addEventListener(...);`

Comment: iframe.onload = () => { .... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not able to access the element is that iframe loading is an asynchronous process. Therefore you can use something like :

`iframe.onload = function() {
  // do something here ;
}`

Another way is to use polling till the element gets loaded, obviously you'll need to add a timeout check there. This is especially useful when you are dealing with external DOM and you're unsure when is it going to load.